# How to apply numpy's integer array indexing both to ndarray-s and python lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Numpy has ["integer array indexig"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), which allows to index `ndarray` with other `ndarray` or list:

```
>> A = np.arange(10,20)
>> A[[1,2,3]]
Out[14]: array([11, 12, 13])
```

Suppose I don't know what is `A`, which can be either `ndarray` or Python's list.

Is there any explicit indexing function in numpy, which would allow the same indexing and accept both types?

For example:

```
>> A = np.arange(10,20)
>> np.get_elements(A, [1,2,3])
Out[14]: array([11, 12, 13])
>> A = range(10,20)
>> np.get_elements(A, [1,2,3])
Out[15]: [11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Use `numpy.take`.

Comment: Do you expect it to return a list if input is a list? A numpy function will first ensure `A` is an array (eg `asarday(A)`).

Comment: Look at `operator.itemgetter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_elements(A, idx):
    try:
        return A[idx]
    except TypeError:
        import operator
        return list(operator.itemgetter(*idx)(A))

In [35]: get_elements(np.arange(10), [1,3,4])
Out[35]: array([1, 3, 4])
In [36]: get_elements(np.arange(10).tolist(), [1,3,4])
Out[36]: [1, 3, 4]
```

`itemgetter` is just a convenience class.  The list comprehension would be just as good

```
In [39]: [A[i] for i in [1,3,4]]
Out[39]: [1, 3, 4]
```

A numpy function like `take` returns an array

```
In [40]: np.take(A,[1,3,4])
Out[40]: array([1, 3, 4])
```

which could be converted back into a list if desired.